# Workflow "suspended" after creating a timed loop in a workflow

Tags: workflow, form, error-handling, loop

Recently discovered "timed" loops in Workflows, that allow me to loop based on a chosen variable (say 3 weeks, therefore loop 3 times). However, the workflow shows "suspended" under the workflow status page with this error:

> RequestorId: eb0e8b41-7248-3ce0-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.InvalidCastException: The value 'Value' cannot be read as type 'Int32'. at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.CheckedRead(String propertyName, DynamicItem value) at Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation) Exception from activity GetDynamicValueProperty Cast BuildDictionary Subroutine Sequence Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.LoopNTimes Then If Stage 1 Sequence Flowchart Sequence Duplicate 1.WorkflowXaml_8c4eecce_76a5_40a3_98a8_a5d2b9ac5d4c

I can't seem to wrap my head around the error and hoping someone can direct me the right direction.

Here's my workflow, basically, i'm checking if the user is using the right form via content type and continue to the loop. Here the loop runs based on what the user entered.

[image]

Any ideas what I should be looking?

Comment: You have a `WeekCount` field in your list: what's its SharePoint type?

Comment: Are you creating item in Same list? Please check if you are adding non-number value in any column with type Number.